# xml data in actionscript 3.0?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

is the target.data, a default structure of whole xml? in as3, should the data of xml loaded through this data itself?

```
function xmlDisplay(e:Event):void
        {
            xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
            trace(xmlData);
        }
```

Comment: yes i got data from urlLoader only from a website which had xml file, what i asked was are target.data is default to access the data and elements of returned XML data?

Comment: please see the additional info in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, e.target is a property of the Event. In this case e.target probably refers to an instance of URLLoader. Thus, e.target.data is a property of URLLoader, which holds the data received from the load operation. You then inject this data into a new XML object. The XML object parses this data to become a true XML object.

**EDIT:**
Well, yes: e.target.data holds the **raw** xml you loaded from the xml file of the website.

However, in order to access and manipulate the xml data you need to insert it into an XML object like you already do with:

```
xmlData = new XML( etc.. );
```

If this is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <image>
        <id>1</id>
        <url>/images/someImage.jpg</url>
    </image>
    <image>
        <id>2</id>
        <url>/images/anotherImage.jpg</url>
    </image>
</root>
```

.. you can access the XMLNode elements like so:

```
trace( xmlData.image[0].id ) // outputs 1
trace( xmlData.image[0].url ) // outputs /images/someImage.jpg
trace( xmlData.image[1].id ) // outputs 2
trace( xmlData.image[1].url ) // outputs /images/anotherImage.jpg
```

There are many more ways to manipulate the XML. See [Adobe's manual about XML](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html) for starters.

Hope this helps.